# How to position the 1.5 kΩ pull-up resistor on USB Type-C D+ connection?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, stm32, usb

I am designing a TYPE C plug with STM32L432KC MCU and was wondering how to physically position the 1.5 kΩ pull-up resistor on D+ connection.
(male plug --- ft323 --- mcu)
Should it be next to the MCU or close to the receptacle or what?
Does it even make a difference?

[image]

Comment: Which exact FT232 model? The MCU is irrelevant if FT232 connects to USB. And what is the purpose of FT232 as the MCU has built-in USB?

Comment: its is FTDI chip i want to connect this product with a mobile so i need a transceiver and  d+ d- from male plug to ft232 and rx and tx from mcu to ftdi232 
https://www.ftdichip.com/old2020/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet says FT232R chip has an internal 1k5 pull-up resistor on D+.

You don't need an external 1k5 resistor on D+.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you may not need the FT232R either. The MCU has a built-in USB, which in most cases could be used communicate USB directly without FT232R.

Comment: can I connect directly mcu with mobile using a type c male plug?

Comment: can I connect directly mcu with mobile using a type c male plug? i want to communicate mcu with mobile app that was I aim so i thought rx and tx from mcu is used for print the needed output and receive the command from mobile app and ft232 works as transreviver d+ and d- for  data from mobile and VBUS for power up the mcu

Comment: @BalajiNadar I believe ST provides an USB library to make an USB "virtual COM port" using CDC ACM and I believe phones support it. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong. But your original question is now answered.